# Player doing small forward movements when hes shooting

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When im shooting my player do small steps forward, what i want is make him stop when hes firing.

I made this method to prevent him from move when he's firing, but he still doing a small forward movements when I hold the movement key.

```
void Move(float movement) {
        if (!this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("shoot")) {
            MyRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * playerSpeed, MyRigidBody.velocity.y);
        } else if(anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("shoot"))
        {
            MyRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using a bool.

```
Public bool isShooting;
```

Set it true when you are shooting and false when you are not shooting. You can use OnPointerUp/OnPointerDown to track event.

### New Move method:

```
void Move(float movement) {
if(!isShooting)
    if (!this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsTag("shoot")) {
        MyRigidBody.velocity = new Vector2(movement * playerSpeed, MyRigidBody.velocity.y);
    } 
}
```